# Why does matplotlib use setters and getters instead of properties?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I guess it sounds like a historical question, so I'd like to frame it as: coding a library such as matplotlib, should I have setters and getters, or should I stick to properties?

Comment: According to the docs, `@property` was "New in version 2.2." I think matplotlib was before this? Maybe some legacy stuff going on?

Comment: This is just a guess though.